# How to make a JPanel scrollable when it has absolute layout?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, scrollable, jscrollbar

I can't for the life of me figure this one out..
I'm fairly new in Java and we have to do this simple JPanel which contains PC's images and information and wanted it to display it with a scrollable JPanel but it just won't work.

```
    pnlVentanaSobremesa = new JPanel();
    pnlVentanaSobremesa.setBackground(SystemColor.inactiveCaption);
    pnlVentanaSobremesa.setLayout(null);
    scrollSobremesa = new JScrollPane(pnlVentanaSobremesa, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    this.add(scrollSobremesa);
```

Then I add a bunch of stuff in pnlVentanaSobremesa, setting the bounds so everything fits nicely.
Also mention that this panel, pnlVentanaSobremesa is made visible after clicking another button so perhaps that might help solve the problem.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You might want to consider posting a [Runnable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which we can copy-paste and see the same issue as you.